# Debugging code on a server running Varnish Cache

Tags: debugging, varnish

Considering installing Varnish Cache on a VPS web server but wondering what issues that might cause if eg php code needs debugging. In the past I've found that caching systems make debugging more difficult because the cached version of a web page does not change immediately following a code change. Ideally debugging needs to all be done on a test site, but sometimes it's necessary to do on a production version.

Can Varnish Cache be temporarily turned off either for individual domains or for the whole server whilst debugging?

Answer (score 2):

None or very little development should be done on a production box, but indeed, sometimes you need to troubleshoot things at live site.

Varnish makes it a bit troublesome to see why a particular request to a page failed: it will mask fatal PHP errors with its own "Backend Fetch Failed" error. This makes it less obvious that there's a problem with your PHP code and makes you immediately blame Varnish.

You can temporarily make Varnish pass through its cache by piping all requests directly to the configured backend. In this way it will work absolutely the same in regards to debugging PHP code (as if Varnish isn't actually there!). My steps for this are:

1. Open your VCL file and immediately after `sub vcl_recv {`, place a line `return (pipe);`
2. Reload your Varnish configuration with `service varnish reload` or `systemctl reload varnish` (depends on your Linux distro).

To go back to caching (production setting), remove the line and reload Varnish again. No downtime when doing these steps.